# Laravel Elixir installation - npm install fails with "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-elixir

I'm following the **[guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#installation)** to install Elixir in my Homestead environment. All goes as planned, but the final `npm install --no-bin-links` command always ends with the error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Before each installation attempt, I delete *node_modules* directory and run `npm cache clear` command, just to be sure.

My setup:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Homestead 0.2.7
- Laravel 5.2
- Node 6.2.0
- NPM 3.8.9

Now, I am aware of the **[issue thread on GitHub](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9224)** that deals with the problem, however I've tried all suggested ways to solve it (except for downgrading Node, as it feels like a bit a random solution) - with no luck.

Does anyone using Elixir had this problem and solved it? I'm on it since yesterday afternoon, so after this fails I'm sicking with Grunt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Homestead runs on Ubuntu, so you should run just `npm install` without the `--no-bin-links` flag, which is for Windows systems.

Comment: Tried it without the flag as well and a different error was thrown, related to /bin/ directories and permissions. Additionally, the guide suggests using the `--no-bin-links` flag on Windows machines, which helps avoiding problems related with /bin/ directories.

Comment: Are you running `npm install` on your Windows machine or inside the Homestead VM?

Comment: Tried both in the VM (Homestead) and locally - same "stack size exceeded" error.

Comment: So you have installed node, npm and global gulp on your VM and when you run `npm install` there you still get this error?

Comment: The file system is defined on the hard drive. Although the Guest machine is a Linux system, the Host machine is Windows and, therefore, running on a NTFS or similar file-system, which won't offer symbolic link feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall before installing your package:

```
npm -g uninstall package;

npm -g install package;
```

[check this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9633)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try run `npm install` once again, after the error.  It worked for me.